# sum the perimeter of a matrix without adding the corners multiple times

Tags: c

I'm trying to sum the perimeter of a matrix of n size using recursion. (without adding the corners multiple times)

What I have written is an infinite loop and doesn't exclude the corners. How do I stop the infinite loop and exclude the corners?

```
int
sumPerimeter(int** matrix, int i, int j, int height, int width)
{
    if (i == 0 && j == 0)
      return matrix[i][j] + sumPerimeter(matrix, i + 1, j, height, width);

   if (i == height && j == 0)
      return matrix[i][j] + sumPerimeter(matrix, i, j + 1, height, width);

   if (i==height&& j == width)
      return matrix[i][j] + sumPerimeter(matrix, i - 1, j, height, width);

   if (i == 0 && j == width)
      return matrix[i][j] + sumPerimeter(matrix, i, j - 1, height, width);
}
```

I decided to break this up into stages to make it easier, the below code is my current attempt. When I step through it with visual studios it works, but it always returns the first number in the matrix.

```
   int
   sumRight(int** matrix, int i, int j, int height, int width,int count)
   {


   if (0 > width)
      return 0;

   if (j > width - 1)
      return count;

      int sum = matrix[i][j];
       count = sum + count;

   sumRight(matrix, i, j + 1, height, width,count);



   return count;

}
```

I figured out why it wasn't returning the right value. But I have no idea how to make it not calculate the corners multiple times. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to use recursion?

Comment: As with all recursion schemes, you need one or more base cases where you can calculate the answer without recursion, and you need to determine what your recursive cases are. It seems to me it would be easier to use iteration than recursion.  If you do use recursion, what are the values of `i` and `j` in the initial call? Supposing they are (0,0); then your code is going to recurse with (1,0), but unless height is 1, the recursive case is not going to execute anything in the function; it isn't even going to return a value as it should.  You've got quite a lot of thinking ahead of you.

Comment: yes I have to use recursion.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I didn't even see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *must* use recursion for this (and that's probably a bad idea since you gain very little but it's probably okay for educational purposes<sup>1</sup>), you could opt for a simple way.

Have the base case be a matrix of zero height and the recurring case be add the sum of the first row to the sum of the rest of the matrix. In other words, something like the following pseudo-code:

```
def sumOfMatrix (matrix m, int row, int height, int width):
    # No rows left, return zero.

    if row == height:
        return 0

    # Get sum of first row.

    sum = 0
    for col in 0..width-1 inclusive:
        sum = sum + m[row][col]

    # Return that plus sum of rest of matrix.

    return sum + sumOfMatrix (m, row+1, height, width)
```

---

If you *really* wanted to be clever, for some bizarre definition of the word "clever" :-), you could do two totally distinct types of recursion, one for a row and another for a matrix:

```
def sumOfRow (matrix m, int row, int col, int width):
    # No columns left, return zero.

    if col == width:
        return 0

    # Get value plus sum of rest of row.

    return m[row][col] + sumOfRow (m, row, col+1, width)

def sumOfMatrix (matrix m, int row, int height, int width):
    # No rows left, return zero.

    if row == height:
        return 0

    # Get sum of this row plus sum of all other rows.

    return sumOfRow (m, row, 0, width) + sumOf (m, row+1, height, width)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As mentioned, this is probably the wrong use case for recursion since you could simply do a compact iterative solution thus:

```
def sumOfMatrix (matrix m, int height, int width):
    sum = 0
    for row = 0..height-1 inclusive:
        for col = 0..width-1 inclusive:
            sum = sum + m[row][col]
    return sum
```

But, if you *need* a recursive solution (because you're self-learning recursion, or your educator is incapable of thinking of better real-world problems), the recursive code above should be enough to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution for traversing rectangle perimeter.

Planar point structure and some helper functions:

```
struct pt { int cx; int cy; };
pt init( int x0, int y0 ) { pt p0; p0.cx = x0; p0.cy = y0; return p0; }
void prpt( pt p0 ) { printf( "(%d;%d)\n", p0.cx, p0.cy ); }

int eq( pt p0, pt p1 )
{
    int rv = 0;
    if( ( p0.cx == p1.cx ) && ( p0.cy == p1.cy ) ) { rv = 1; }
    return rv;
}

int perim( pt curr, pt size )
{
    int rv = 0;
    if( ( 0 <= curr.cx ) && ( curr.cx < size.cx ) 
     && ( 0 <= curr.cy ) && ( curr.cy < size.cy ) )
    {
        if( ( ( 0 == curr.cx ) || ( ( 1 + curr.cx ) == size.cx ) ) 
           || ( 0 == curr.cy ) || ( ( 1 + curr.cy ) == size.cy ) ) { rv = 1; }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

From a perimeter point next can be advanced in 4 directions, but only 2 of them would be on perimeter too. Stepping back prevented by recalling previous position. Originating point have to be stored too in order to end traversal. Recursion:

```
void fun( pt size, pt orig, pt prev, pt curr )
{
    pt next;
    if( perim( curr, size ) && ( !eq( curr, orig ) || eq( curr, prev ) ) )
    {
        prpt( curr );

        next = curr; next.cy += 1; // N
        if( !eq( next, prev ) ) { fun( size, orig, curr, next ); }

        next = curr; next.cx += 1; // E
        if( !eq( next, prev ) ) { fun( size, orig, curr, next ); }

        next = curr; next.cy -= 1; // S
        if( !eq( next, prev ) ) { fun( size, orig, curr, next ); }

        next = curr; next.cx -= 1; // W
        if( !eq( next, prev ) ) { fun( size, orig, curr, next ); }
    }
}
```

Origin, current and previous points are the same at first call. Traverses both direction of a 7x5 rectangle from a chosen point in this example:

```
pt size = init( 7, 5 );
pt orig = init( 0, 0 );
pt prev = orig;
pt curr = orig;
fun( size, orig, prev, curr );
```

Based on this a sum calculating traversal is up to you.